# Ошибка в Wine. Не найден драйверр

Tags: linux, fedora, wine

Работаю на fedora 38 x11. С недавних пор  стала появляться ошибка в вайне при инициализации окна.

```
12c:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
012c:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow L"The explorer process failed to start."
013c:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
013c:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow L"The explorer process failed to start."
013c:fixme:win:DisableProcessWindowsGhosting : stub
013c:fixme:graphics:ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy (00000000): stub
013c:fixme:graphics:ShutdownBlockReasonCreate (00000000, L"\0423\0441\0442\0430\043d\043e\0432\043a\0430..."): stub
013c:fixme:rstrtmgr:RmStartSession 00556F40, 0, 00556F44 stub!
013c:err:module:import_dll Library MFC42u.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\users\\uzver\\Temp\\is-O6Q9E.tmp\\isskinexW.dll") not found
013c:fixme:rstrtmgr:RmEndSession 3735928559 stub!
013c:fixme:graphics:ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy (00000000): stub
```

Вино переустанавливал, драйвера на видеокарту стоят (проприентанрые)

Comment: ' ibrary MFC42u.DLL (which is needed by L"C:\\users\\uzver\\Temp\\is-O6Q9E.tmp\\isskinexW.dll") not found '
Заметил, но как установить не знаю

Comment: winetricks dlls mfc42

Comment: @eri 027c:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
027c:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow L"The explorer process failed to start."
------------------------------------------------------
warning: Важно: команда wine /home/uzver/.cache/winetricks/vcrun6/VC6RedistSetup_deu.exe /T:C:\windows\Temp /c вернула статус 199. Прерывание.
------------------------------------------------------

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема крылась в неправильной установке драйверов Nvidia. После переустановки все работает! Так же стоит переустановить Вайн